# What would be a regex to replace/remove END where its not been preceded by an unended START?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What would be a regex (PHP) to replace/remove (using `preg_replace()`) END where its not been preceded by an unended START?

Here are a few examples to portray what I mean better:

**Example 1:**

*Input:*

```
sometext....END
```

*Output:*

```
sometext.... //because theres no START, therefore no need for the excess END
```

**Example 2:**

*Input:*

```
STARTsometext....END
```

*Output:*

```
STARTsometext....END //because its preceded by a START
```

**Example 3:**

*Input:*

```
STARTsometext....END.......END
```

*Output:*

```
STARTsometext....END....... //because the END is not preceded by a START
```

Hoping someone can help?

Thank You.

Comment: If you want a parser, you need to write a parser.

Comment: Once you get to the point of having to recognize levels of nested delimiters (parens, brackets, start/end, etc.), you should probably consider using a parsing library, or even rolling your own simple pushdown automaton, instead of a regular expression.  Even if your platform's regex library supports extensions that would make this possible, the solution is likely to be fragile and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I'm not looking for a parser more of a small regex to fix excess END. My regex skills are limited as i'm not sure how i'd check if its no proceeded by START to replace it?

Comment: This is not a pattern you can match with a regular expression. Nobody will be able to provide you with a small regex to do this. It's not a matter of your skills.

Comment: echo preg_replace('#(?<!START)END#', '', $str); works but not sure as to what to place in between i've tried .*? but gives an error.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure there is a small regex that can remove those `END` s, but a few clarifications: 1. How many start/end sequences are there in every line? 2. Can they be nested? 3. Should a `Start` always be right after the previous `End`, e.g., `S...ES...E`, or `...S...E.....S...E...E`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you aren't looking for nested pairs, there is a simple solution to remore excess ENDs. Consider:

```
$str = preg_replace("/END|(START.*?END)/", "$1", $str);
```

This is a little backwards replacement, but it makes sense if you understand the order in which the engine works. First, the regex is made of two main parts: `END|()`. The alternations are tried from left to right, so if the engine sees an `END` in the input string, it will match it and move on to the next match (that is, look for `END` again).
The second part is a capturing group, which contains `START.*?END` - this will match an entire Start/End token if possible. Everything else will be skipped, until it finds another END or START.

Since we use `$1` in the replace, which is the captured group, we only save the second token. Therefor, the only way for an `END` to survive is to get into the capturing group, by being the first one after a `START`.

For example, for the text `END START 123 END abc END`. The regex will find the following matches, and keep, skip or remove them accordingly:

- `END` - Removed
- `(START 123 END)` - Captured
- `a` - Skip
- `b` - Skip
- `c` - Skip
- `END` - Removed

Working example: http://ideone.com/suVYh

Comment: Terrific answer using capture groups. Love it. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a textbook example of a non-regular language (START and END are the equivalent of opening and closing parentheses). That means you cannot match this language with a simple regular expression. You can do it to some specific depth with a complicated regex, but not arbitrary depth.

You need to write a language parser.

Related reading:

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Automata-Theory-Languages-Computation/dp/0321462254/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1291768284&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321462254)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write a regular expression for all possible syntax. For your case you might need a context free parser like an ascendent or descendent one. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar